# The traitor Bamu Cormorant - historical inspiration for the "favorite method"?

Tags: inspiration, the-traitor-baru-cormorant

In *The Traitor Bamu Cormorant* a significant development near the end happens when

> the revolt turns out to be orchestrated by the Empire, just to get all the potential rebels to revolt, so as to get rid of them.

Has there been an historical analog to this?

> The monetary trick she pulls at her arrival in Aurdwynn does have a distant analog in the courts of the Late Shogunate and Louis XIV - lords were ordered to be at court and had to be thrown costly parties - the intent being to keep them from amassing enough wealth to afford sedition against the central government.

Comment: Maybe Caligula?

Comment: I've tried to edit up your post a little to make it a little more appropriate. Having one big wall of "spoilers" doesn't really help anyone.

Comment: txs.  I tried to split it up by paragraphs like you did but kept on getting everything visible instead.  will take a look at your markdown for sure!

Answer (score 2):

There is a phrase for someone assigned to do that or similar deeds: agent provocateur.

> An agent provocateur (French for "inciting agent") is a person who commits, or who acts to entice another person to commit an illegal or rash act or falsely implicate them in partaking in an illegal act. An agent provocateur may be acting out of their own sense of duty or may be employed by the police or other entity to discredit or harm another group (such as a peaceful protest or demonstration) by provoking them to commit a crime, thereby undermining the protest or demonstration as a whole.
>
> In accordance with French grammar, the plural form of the term is, agents provocateurs; a female agent is an agente provocatrice.
>
> To prevent infiltration by agents provocateurs, the organizers of large or controversial assemblies may deploy and coordinate demonstration marshals, also called stewards.
>
> <sub>—[Agent provocateur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_provocateur), Wikipedia</sub>

The article lists examples from the 19th, 20th, and 21st centuries.

There is a legal term for when undercover agents of the police get someone to agree to or actually commit a crime they otherwise would not have done: [entrapment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entrapment).

And I have read a number of accounts of ancient and medieval events in which it was claimed that agents provocateurs pretended to be someone's friends and provoked them into saying or doing something that would get them executed.

So it would not be totally unlikely for government agents provocateurs to start a revolt against their government if they believed the revolt was certain to be defeated, or if they goofed and went too far trying to catch traitors.

There have been hundreds and thousands of rebellions in history.  And some of them have failed so totally and so fast that one might suspect they were actually planned by the government to identify and eliminate the disloyal.

Comment: upvoted, but looking for examples of a full-on revolt, not *just* a few agitators provoking things during a riot or exposing members of the underground.